# I need some assistance in making an email activation with php oop syntax

Tags: php

I have almost got my code to work but would prefer to use my user class 
but when implementing $user = new User() into my registration.php file, it 
won't work. I have got the following codes so far. This is only part of the code..

```
<?php
 require_once 'core/init.php';  // we have autoloader here


 if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

      $random = rand();
      $name = $_POST['name'];
      $email = $_POST['email'];
      $to = 'piano0011@hotmail.com';

      $header = 'From: piano0011@hotmail.com';

      $subject = 'Email activation is required';
      $message = <<<EMAIL

      Hello $name How are you? Thank you for registering and please 
      click on the link to activate your account: 
      .http://localhost/pianocourse101/activate.php? 
      email=$_POST['email']

      EMAIL;

      mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);
}
```

I hope that these are enough codes but will be happy to provide more coding...

I am also getting the following errors when including the activation link 
       http://

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), 
>           expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number 
>           (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\pianocourse101\register.php on line 17

However, I would prefer to do something like $user->data()->username
but I am not sure how to go about in doing this. I managed to do it in my profile.php but for some reason when I tried it here, it says something about non-object error.. I am not sure what non-object means but I included the $user = new User(); line which should work...I am new to php and would like a simple step by step explanation

```
if($validation->passed()) {

  $user = new User();

  $salt = Hash::salt(32);


 try {
     $user->create(array(
    'username' => Input::get('username'),
    'password' => Hash::make(Input::get('password'), $salt),
    'salt' => $salt,
    'name' => Input::get('name'),
    'joined' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'group' => 0,
    'email' => Input::get('email'),
    'activated' => 0,
    'country' => Input::get('country'),
    'token' => Input::get('token'),
    'email_code' => Hash::make(Input::get('username', microtime()))

     ));



    Session::flash('home', 'You have been registered and can now log in!');
   // Redirect::to('index.html');


    } catch(Exception $e) {
      die($e->getMessage());
    }
 } else {
    foreach($validation->errors() as $error) {
      echo $error, '<br>';
    }
 }





<form action="" method="post" id="simpleform">
<div class ="field">      
<label for="username">Username</label>
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="<?php echo 
escape(Input::get('username')); ?>" autocomplete="off">
</div>
```

Comment: Please, don't forget to close your question if an answer solves your problem. Thanks! See [How does accepting an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Answer (score 3):

You Heredoc format is not good. The close element must not be indented:

```
    $message = <<<EMAIL

         Hello $name How are you? Thank you for registering and please 
         click on the link to activate your account: 
         .http://localhost/pianocourse101/activate.php? 
         email=$_POST['email']

EMAIL; // on the first column
```

From [documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc):

> It is very important to note that the line with the closing identifier must contain no other characters, except a semicolon (;). That means especially that **the identifier may not be indented**, and there may not be any spaces or tabs before or after the semicolon. It's also important to realize that the first character before the closing identifier must be a newline as defined by the local operating system. This is \n on UNIX systems, including Mac OS X. The closing delimiter must also be followed by a newline.